# fedora 19: unable to update or install - "Could not resolve host..."

Tags: fedora

I cannot update as no mirror is found:

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum update
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Could not get metalink https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-19&arch=i386 error was
14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrors.fedoraproject.org; Name or service not known"
http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/19/Everything/i386/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: www.mirrorservice.org; Name or service not known"
Trying other mirror.
ftp://ftp.mirrorservice.org/sites/dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/19/Everything/i386/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: ftp.mirrorservice.org; Name or service not known"
Trying other mirror.
```

I can ping this and every other address that fails:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ping www.mirrorservice.org
PING www.mirrorservice.org (212.219.56.184) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from www.mirrorservice.org (212.219.56.184): icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=19.6 ms
64 bytes from www.mirrorservice.org (212.219.56.184): icmp_seq=2 ttl=50 time=19.6 ms
64 bytes from www.mirrorservice.org (212.219.56.184): icmp_seq=3 ttl=50 time=19.7 ms
64 bytes from www.mirrorservice.org (212.219.56.184): icmp_seq=4 ttl=50 time=20.1 ms
^C
--- www.mirrorservice.org ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 19.607/19.788/20.104/0.189 ms
```

#### UPDATE #1

Here's the [output](http://paste2.org/sEMNwgHz) from the following command:

```
$ URLGRABBER_DEBUG=1,debug.log yum update
```

Comment: Can you run it manually? `curl http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/19/Everything/i386/os/repodata/repomd.xml`

Comment: that giving issue `Could not resolve host: mirrors.fedoraproject.org; Name or service not known` So are you able to resolve `mirrors.fedoraproject.org` ? if possible post `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: [root@localhost ~]# ping mirrors.fedoraproject.org
PING mirrors.fedoraproject.org (152.19.134.146) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from vm7.fedora.ibiblio.org (152.19.134.146): icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=112 ms
64 bytes from vm7.fedora.ibiblio.org (152.19.134.146): icmp_seq=2 ttl=47 time=114 ms
^C
--- mirrors.fedoraproject.org ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 112.452/113.565/114.678/1.113 ms

Comment: Adding the bytemark mirror to /etc/hosts has allowed me to update and install a browser... so there is something off in the way yum is DNSing?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this by adding `nameserver 8.8.8.8` above my router's address in `resolv.conf` that was obtained by DHCP.

Not quite sure why it will not work with the automagic DHCP settings.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

#### metalink

Double check that you can download the metalink file from here:

```
$ curl 'https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-19&arch=i386' \
    -o metalink
```

#### ping fedoraproject

It looks like you're having an issue getting to that URL and not www.mirrorservice.org. Also make sure you can ping this site:

```
$ ping mirrors.fedoraproject.org
```

#### Other URLs in metalink file

Also if the `metalink` file is downloaded correctly, take a look inside it. There are additional URLs to repos in there, make sure that they're accessible too.

#### Turn up the debugging level

You can use this command to get more feedback from `yum` as to why it is unable to connect to repositories:

```
$ URLGRABBER_DEBUG=1,debug.log yum update
```

The output will be dumped to the screen and to the log file, debug.log. Please post this file using pastebin.com.

Comment: All of the mirrors fail but all can be pinged!`[root@localhost ~]# ping mirror.bytemark.co.uk
PING mirror.bytemark.co.uk (212.110.161.69) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from mirror.bytemark.co.uk (212.110.161.69): icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=26.3 ms
64 bytes from mirror.bytemark.co.uk (212.110.161.69): icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=26.5 ms
64 bytes from mirror.bytemark.co.uk (212.110.161.69): icmp_seq=3 ttl=51 time=26.9 ms
^C
--- mirror.bytemark.co.uk ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 26.356/26.629/26.967/0.253 ms`

Comment: Pinging just proves that they're accessible via the network, not that the service is actually running at the other end that yum can connect to. See if your yum data files have become corrupted and remove them w/ this cmd: `yum clean all`.

Comment: Ping also proves they can be resolved which contradicts the error message. With 'yum clean all' the error persists.

Comment: @Stramash - true but the message says both: "Name or service not known".

Comment: @Stramash - see updates, please post the debug.log file I showed how to get.

Comment: @Stramash - also please try to curl this package: http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/abrt/abrt/fedora-19/x86_64/abrt-2.1.7.30.g9227.dirty-1.fc19.x86_64.rpm

Comment: [debug output](http://paste2.org/sEMNwgHz)

Comment: `bash-4.2$ curl http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/abrt/abrt/fedora-19/x86_64/abrt-2.1.7.30.g9227.dirty-1.fc19.x86_64.rpm
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: repos.fedorapeople.org; Name or service not known`

`bash-4.2$ ping repos.fedorapeople.org
PING repos.fedorapeople.org (152.19.134.191) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from vm11.fedora.ibiblio.org (152.19.134.191): icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 time=111 ms`
`bash-4.2$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.9.5-301.fc19.i686 #1 SMP Tue Jun 11 20:01:50 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
`

Answer (score 0):

Disable the IPV6 then everything works.

To completely disable IPv6 in your system, all you have to do is save the following line in a file (anyname.conf) inside `/etc/modprobe.d/`.

`install ipv6 /bin/true`

And sometimes your dns server may not powerful enough so use google open dns. for that go to `/etc/resolv.conf`
comment all the lines and add below two lines

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Do not restart the system. if restart `/etc/resolv.conf` file will be replace.

Here is the blog post I wrote with step by step guide: http://codeketchup.blogspot.sg/2014/07/how-to-fix-curl-6-could-not-resolve.html